# I have a Danish alien's passport, can I transit through Canada with it?

Tags: transit, passports, canada

I have a Danish [alien's passport](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/asylum/passport_application.htm) which is valid for five years, can I transit through Canada with it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by an 'alien passport'? And what country are you actually a citizen of?

Comment: @DJClayworth: https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/asylum/passport_application.htm

Comment: Are you a Convention Refugee?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Canadian Government site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-all.asp#eta-exemptions), you will need a visa in advance if you hold an alien's passport:

> **Note**: Holders of Alien’s passport and Stateless individuals need a visa to visit or transit in Canada.

Another page ([Transit Without A Visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp)) states the following:

> All nationals who qualify for the TWOV program must also meet these conditions:
>
> - They hold a **valid passport** or travel document **issued by the country of which they are a citizen**;

This does not include you, since the alien's passport is issued by Denmark, which is not your country of citizenship (that's clear because you hold an alien's passport).

Bottom line, visit a Canadian embassy/consulate to issue a transit visa in advance.

Comment: They might not need to go to a VAC, they can apply [online](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp) too

Comment: @blackbird57 No, I do not think so. The [eTA page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta-start.asp) specifically say: "You cannot apply using a Refugee Travel Document"

Comment: That's for eTA though, you have to have a visa-exempt passport for that, which if I understand isn't the OP's case. "...A valid passport from a visa-exempt country"

Comment: The link you provided takes us to eTA page.. is there another online application I am not aware of?

Comment: Yep, right under that section there's "Apply for a visitor visa: 
You can apply online or on paper..." and then you can expand the "Apply online for a visitor visa" section

Comment: @blackbird57  I have seen that, and answered the questions to check the eligibility, there is no field for alien's passport, and it suggests based on the OP's information to get an eTA, but then eTA says it is not allowed for alien's passports. So the only way is to do it on paper, IMO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31705/discussion-between-blackbird57-and-nean-der-thal).

Comment: My passport is a travel refugee document

Comment: What about UK can I transit airside by it "by my Danish alien's passport" ???

Comment: @Amal.z ask another question about that.

Comment: @NeanDerThal ok:)